# Store Tensorflow variable in a class

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to develop my own deep learning library to enhance my knowledge and gain some experience. I am using Tensorflow. I am done with fully connected layers and trying to implement LSTM. I will use LSTM for character level joke generation.

My question is, I want to store previous hidden state in my LSTM class and update the Tensorflow Variable. Is this possible in Tensorflow? I am not sure this works since Tensorflow variables are intialized beforehand. I have implemented LSTM like the following:

```
    def feed(self, input_tensor):
    with self.graph.as_default():
        with tf.name_scope(self.name):
            i_t = tf.sigmoid(
                tf.matmul(input_tensor, self.weights['W_i']) +
                tf.matmul(self.hidden_state, self.weights['U_i']) +
                self.biases['b_i']
            )

            C_head_t = tf.tanh(
                tf.matmul(input_tensor, self.weights['W_c']) +
                tf.matmul(self.hidden_state, self.weights['U_c']) +
                self.biases['b_c']
            )

            f_t = tf.sigmoid(
                tf.matmul(input_tensor, self.weights['W_f']) +
                tf.matmul(self.hidden_state, self.weights['U_f']) +
                self.biases['b_f']
            )

            next_cell_state = tf.multiply(i_t, C_head_t) + tf.multiply(f_t, self.cell_state)

            o_t = tf.sigmoid(
                tf.matmul(input_tensor, self.weights['W_o']) +
                tf.matmul(self.hidden_state, self.weights['U_o']) +
                self.biases['b_o']
            )

            next_hidden_state = tf.multiply(o_t, tf.tanh(next_cell_state))

            self.hidden_state = tf.assign(ref=self.hidden_state, value=next_hidden_state)
            self.cell_state = tf.assign(ref=self.cell_state, value=next_cell_state)

            tf.summary.histogram('hidden_state', self.hidden_state)
            tf.summary.histogram('cell_state', self.cell_state)
            for k, v in self.weights.items():
                tf.summary.histogram(k, v)
            for k, v in self.biases.items():
                tf.summary.histogram(k, v)

            return next_hidden_state
```

And I form Tensorflow Graph like the following:

```
self.feed_forward = self.input_tensor
for l in self.layers:
    self.feed_forward = l.feed(self.feed_forward)

self.loss_opt = self.loss_function(self.feed_forward, self.output_tensor)
self.fit_opt = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss_opt)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
self.sess.run(init)
```

Then I run feed_forward variable in a session to predict, fit_opt variable to update the model.

I connected LSTM layer with a fully connected layer. I believe that fully connected layer works fine since I tested it on a basic dataset. LSTM's hidden state is input to a fully connected layer. softmax_cross_entropy used as a loss function and AdamOptimizer is used to update the model.

I'm getting meaningless results when I train my LSTM. I think that hidden state and cell state updates does not work properly. What is the best way to debug my models? I looked at my graph and tensor histograms through Tensorboard. Graph looks fine and histograms are updated through time.

I suspect the following part

```
self.hidden_state = tf.assign(ref=self.hidden_state, value=next_hidden_state)
self.cell_state = tf.assign(ref=self.cell_state, value=next_cell_state)
```

PS: I use truncated_normal to initialize the trensors. Cell state and hidden state variables has trainable=False and their initial value is zero vector.

https://github.com/ceteke/MyNN here you can find the whole code.

I am using the algorithm: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html